# How to paste a PNG image with transparency to another image in PIL without white pixels?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two images, a background and a PNG image with transparent pixels. I am trying to paste the PNG onto the background using Python-PIL but when I paste the two images I get white pixels around the PNG image where there were transparent pixels.

My code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

filename='pikachu.png'
ironman = Image.open(filename, 'r')
filename1='bg.png'
bg = Image.open(filename1, 'r')
text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (600,320), (0, 0, 0, 0))
text_img.paste(bg, (0,0))
text_img.paste(ironman, (0,0))
text_img.save("ball.png", format="png")
```

My images:
[image] [image]

**my output image:**
[image]

How can I have transparent pixels instead of white?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to specify the image as the mask as follows in the paste function:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

filename = 'pikachu.png'
ironman = Image.open(filename, 'r')
filename1 = 'bg.png'
bg = Image.open(filename1, 'r')
text_img = Image.new('RGBA', (600,320), (0, 0, 0, 0))
text_img.paste(bg, (0,0))
text_img.paste(ironman, (0,0), mask=ironman)
text_img.save("ball.png", format="png")
```

Giving you:

[image: paste with transparency]

---

To centre both the background image and the transparent image on the new `text_img`, you need to calculate the correct offsets based on the images dimensions:

```
text_img.paste(bg, ((text_img.width - bg.width) // 2, (text_img.height - bg.height) // 2))
text_img.paste(ironman, ((text_img.width - ironman.width) // 2, (text_img.height - ironman.height) // 2), mask=ironman)
```

Comment: thank you very much it works,but when i tried to do the same with image from internet URL i got the error `bad transparency mask` can you tell me reason for that?

Comment: It probably depends on the image, can you give me a link to the image? You could also try `mask=ironman.split()[3]`

Comment: what does the function `.split()[3]` do here?

Comment: It is passing just the mask layer rather than the whole image.

Comment: thank you again for your patience, you were very helpful!

Comment: @MartinEvans Do u know how to also center it with the transparent images original size?

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez, I have added a short explanation to show how both image can be centred on the new image. You just need to calculate a suitable offset instead of using `(0, 0)`

Comment: I get this error when running it: `integer argument expected, got float`

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/`

Comment: Awesome :) Works great! Thanks a ton!

Comment: FYI the alpha channel is not required