# PIL: pasting an image onto another image, calculate position

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to paste one image onto antoher but can't calculate positions other than left top corner. How to calculate position for right top/bottom corner and left bottom corner?

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


def add_watermark():
    original_image = Image.open('test1.jpg')
    watermark = Image.open('watermark.png')

    watermark_width, watermark_height = watermark.size

    x, y = original_image.size
    margin = 40

    # left top
    position = ((0 + margin, 0 + margin))

    image_with_watermark = Image.new('RGBA', (x, y), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    image_with_watermark.paste(original_image, (0, 0))
    image_with_watermark.paste(watermark, position, mask=watermark)
    image_with_watermark.show()
    buffer = BytesIO()
    image_with_watermark.save(fp=buffer, format='jpeg')


add_watermark()
```

Comment: This link might help: [paste an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38629258/4985733)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following for top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right:

```
position_tl = (0 + margin, 0 + margin)
position_tr = (x - margin - watermark_width, 0 + margin)
position_bl = (0 + margin, y - margin - watermark_height)
position_br = (x - margin - watermark_width, y - margin - watermark_height)
```

Comment: ValueError: images do not match in this line `image_with_watermark.paste(watermark, position, mask=watermark)`

Comment: Don't use the `mask` argument. Look at my second replacement.

Comment: still the same, btw. original image is .jpg, watermark is .png in my case