# I'm looking to superimpose two images, one of which is transparent

Tags: python, image, render

I'm trying to superimpose two images, knowing that one of them is already transparent!

I looked on the web for a little bit of what had already been done, here is what I found and adapted to me :

```
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\signature\signature_1.png")

background = Image.open(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\photo_1\oui_1.png")

background.paste(img, (0, 0), new_img)
background.save('how_to_superimpose_two_images_01.png',"PNG")
```

---

### AND

```
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\signature\signature_1.png")
new_image = Image.new("RGBA", img.size, "WHITE")

background = Image.open(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\photo_1\oui_1.png")

background.paste(img, (0, 0), new_img)
background.save('how_to_superimpose_two_images_01.png',"PNG")
```

My transparent image is well placed in front of my other image but the transparent part has turned green and therefore hides the other image

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Is this post relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627870/how-to-paste-a-png-image-with-transparency-to-another-image-in-pil-without-white/38629258

Comment: Yes, because the answer that worked for this gentleman doesn't work for me !

Comment: It seems like you're loading the foreground Image as RGBA but not the background, as was shown in the other post?

Comment: In my program, yes, but even when I try the program you told me, the result remains the same

Comment: Have you tried different images? The image you have might not be truly transparent.

Comment: in fact, I just did a pixel color test, the image appears as a render on photofilter but its pixels are not in (255,255,255,255) and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trouble, I finally made it! ( I write it for the next guys who will struggle on it!)

The function that makes the image transparent: ( here, it is all the black pixels that are transparent, you can change this value there of course)

```
from PIL import Image
```

def transparent_1(myimage) :

```
img = Image.open(myimage) # ex : fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\signature\signature_1.png"
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 0 and item[1] == 0 and item[2] == 0:
        newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("image_transparente.png", "PNG") # ca enregistre l'image dans le même dossier que là où est le code
```

The function that overlays the two images:

```
from PIL import Image
```

def superposer_img(ft,bg): # ft = front , bg = background

```
filename = ft
front = Image.open(filename, 'r')
filename1 = bg
background = Image.open(filename1, 'r')
text_img = Image.new('RGBA', background.size , (0, 0, 0, 0))
text_img.paste(background, (0,0))
text_img.paste(front, (0,0), mask=front)
text_img.save("image.png", format="png")
```

And the program that calls the functions:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Fonction")

from Superposer_image import superposer_img as supimg
from Image_Transparente import transparent_1 as tr


tr(fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes quoi\signature\signature_1.png")

supimg("image_transparente.png",fr"D:\Prog\Automatisation\Photo tu preferes 
quoi\photo_1\a.png")
```