# Pasting a png on to another png without covering up the background image (pillow)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

As the name of the suggests I want to paste a `png` onto another `png`. However when I try to do this it's kinda like PIL changes the pixels occupied by the alpha channel to to be transparent.

Here's an example to show you what I mean.

First I make a solid green  block and save it as a `png`

```
im = Image.new("RGBA", (500,500),(,150,0,255))
im.save(r".\test.png")
```

The image look like this:

[image]

Next I make a second, smaller, fully transparent image and paste that on the saved image.

```
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (0,0,0,0))
im3 = Image.open(r".\test.png")
im3.paste(im2,(0,0))
im3.save(r".\test.png")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What I want is for that last image to look like the first one. After pasting the transparent block onto it.

Comment: `.paste()` uses a separate mask image to specify where to change pixels.  You want `.alpha_composite()` to use the image's own alpha channel as the mask.

Comment: Ah i see. I finally found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627870/how-to-paste-a-png-image-with-transparency-to-another-image-in-pil-without-white?rq=1) asking the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as commented by @jasonharper,

> `.paste()` uses a separate mask image to specify where to change pixels. You want `.alpha_composite()` to use the image's own alpha channel as the mask.

A function that does the same is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image


def func(bg: Image.Image, fg: Image.Image, coordinates: tuple[int, int] = (0, 0)) -> Image.Image:
    """Paster ``fg`` on ``bg`` using its alpha channel

    Args:
        bg (Image.Image): the background image.
        fg (Image.Image): the foreground image.
        coordinates (tuple[int,int], optional): the coordinates at which ``fg`` need to be pasted. Defaults to (0,0).

    Returns:
        Image.Image: the final image
    """
    bg.paste(fg, coordinates, fg)
    return bg
```

You can replicate your example by :
you can learn more about them: [`paste()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.htmlhighlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.paste) and [`alpha_composite()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=paste#PIL.Image.Image.alpha_composite).

(PS: this is my first answer on stackoverflow)