# How to paste an image on top of another, the empty pixels of the background remain empty Python PIL

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-masking

I want to paste the first image (which is a simple vertical gradient, from transparent to black), at the bottom of the background.
The empty pixels in the background need to remain empty, and the rounded corners must be preserved. I know I need to use some combination of `alpha_composite`, `paste` and `masking` but really could not figure it out.
How can I achieve this using python pillow library?

[Paste image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpatg.png)

[Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy1Pu.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tsEf.jpg)

Comment: I can't tell on my phone.  Are the empty pixels on the background white or transparent?

Comment: Your images have different widths and heights, but you give no  indication of where the overlay is to be pasted‍♂️

Comment: @MarkRansom they're transparent.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't think the width matters, because we can easily extend or shrink the width of gradient image. You can assume we'll paste such that top left of gradient is on the top left of background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paste a PNG image with transparency to another image in PIL without white pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627870/how-to-paste-a-png-image-with-transparency-to-another-image-in-pil-without-white)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Not really - the linked answer will lose the transparent cutouts on the original background, which is why I put the original alpha channel aside and then pushed it back afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open background and ensure RGBA
bg = Image.open('bg.png').convert('RGBA')

# Open foreground, ensure RGBA and match to size of background
fg = Image.open('fg.png').convert('RGBA').resize(bg.size)

# Put aside background alpha channel
bgA = bg.getchannel('A')

# Paste foreground over background with alpha
bg.paste(fg, mask=fg)

# Reapply transparent cut-outs from original background
bg.putalpha(bgA)

bg.save('result.png')
```

[image]